# (Node.js) Splitting JS class into modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, coding-style, refactoring

I have a class "Firebase" in which I write all the functions (that involve this service) used in my server side.

At first, the code was pretty clean and clear, as there were not a lot of functions in this class. Now, the class is super giant (more than 100 functions not very short). This is why I have decided to divide the class into modules (maybe not correct) to improve the clarity and organization of the project.

Something like this:

```
/* eslint-disable no-empty */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Lazy initialization of the admin SDK
try {
     const googleCloudServiceAccount = require("../../utils/json/googleCloudServiceAccount.json");
     admin.initializeApp({
       credential: admin.credential.cert(googleCloudServiceAccount),
       databaseURL: URL,
       storageBucket: BUCKET,
     });
} catch (e) {}

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, {
      auth: admin.auth(),
      firestore: admin.firestore(),
      storage: admin.storage(),
    });
  }
}

Object.assign(Firebase.prototype, {
  /* Methods */
});

module.exports = Firebase;
```

What I have in mind is to organize the code in modules like "firebase-auth.js", "firebase-storage.js", "firebase-firestore.js"... and finally, require all the modules methods (or something better, because it can be a really long list of imports) and assign them to my Firebase class prototype.

My question is: If in the methods of the modules I need to use Firebase.firestore, Firebase.auth... (which are members of the Firebase class), should I create an instance of the class in each module?

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, is not best but works as expectly

create a file with functions in export module like:

```
module.exports = function (app, dbConnection, firebase) {
       exampleFirebaseFunction(){
       }
}
```

and in your main file you call it as:

```
require('./routes/firebase-routes.js')(app, dbConnection, firebase);
```